# Flexbox - Wrap Column of Three Rows To Fit Height Of Two

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

New to Flexbox and trying to understand how it works. I have a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-wave-k6lmg?file=/src/App.js) of my React /bootstrap code so far... I am creating a clock component, and it will have two buttons (one to increase time, the other to decrease). Here's an image:

[image]

I would like to retain the height of this component as it is perfect for me at the moment, however I would like to add three rows of buttons (Start, Pause, 1st) in a separate column next to this. I would like this second column to wrap and match the height of the clock to the left. However, this is what I get:

[image]

I've tried creating two flexboxes but I'm not sure how to get one to reference the height of the other and resize as such. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `flexbox`, it is easy to achieve this.

As you can see in the below snippet. I have recreated your requirement.

But the up/down buttons are currently given with a space in between to align the same with the right most buttons (3 buttons).

If you want to fill the 2 buttons the entire space, you can give a padding to those buttons to match with the 3 buttons column.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper,
.clock-wrapper,
.action-wrapper,
.btn-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.btn-wrapper button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.action-wrapper,
.btn-wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

input {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="clock-wrapper">
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
      <button>Up</button>
      <button>Down</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="10:35" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
      <button>Up</button>
      <button>Down</button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="action-wrapper">
    <button>Start</button>
    <button>Reset</button>
    <button>1st</button>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.btns-column button {
  height:50%
}
```

Add this if you want to align the up and down buttons as the clock height,

'btns-column' have height by the flexbox, you did it right but the buttons need to wrap the height of 'btns-column'

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-parm-fs9vk?file=/src/styles.css,   check this for result